# Argument in message expression is an uninitialized value (imageFile)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I looked this up several times before and I tried what the answers said but when I run Xcode's analyzer, it says the same "argument in message expression is an uninitialized value".
This is the switch statement:

`

```
NSString *imageFile;
switch (randomCoinType) {


    case 1:



        imageFile = @"coin.1.png";
        break;

    case 2:

        imageFile = @"coin.2.png";
        break;

    case 3:
    case 4:
        imageFile = @"coin.3.png";
        break;

    case 5:
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 8:
        imageFile = @"coin.4.png";
        break;

    case 9:
        imageFile = @"coin.5.png";
        break;

    case 0:
        imageFile = @"coin.6.png";
        break;

    default: 

        break;


      }


//argument in message is uninitialized here!
Coins *c = [Coins spriteWithFile:imageFile];




c.type = type;
c.position = position;
c.velocity = ccp(0,0);
[coins addObject:c];
[self addChild:c z:2];
```

}

`

Comment: "default: nil; break;" is a superfluous statement. It does nothing. It's the same as "default: break;" or just removing the default block altogether.

Comment: I was reading that it was supposed to help in another one of these types of threads.

Answer (score 1):

If your `default` statement is called, then `imageFile` is `nil` and `spriteWithFile` doesn't know what to do. Make sure that you either handle the `nil` statement passed by `default`, or set `imagefile` to something useable inside of the default case.

Comment: That was just an experiment I tried after reading it in another thread. And default won't be called ever.

Comment: what happens if you comment out the switch case and just run `Coins *c = [Coins spriteWithFile:@"coin6.png"];`

Comment: nothing (no coin shows up). So is the `Coins *c = [Coins spriteWithFile:imageFile];` line where the problem is? Or is it earlier?